# How to use an external interpreter for Maya?

Tags: python, dll, maya

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
import maya.standalone
ImportError: No module named maya.standalone
```

This is my condition:

1. Python version provided by Maya
2. Environment variable `PYTHONPATH` set to `sitepackages` folder and `MAYA_LOCATION` to Maya root folder
3. `site-packages` address appended to `sys.path`

`dll` files are here in this address `%:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\DLLs`
I set the environment to address above and still got the same error

Why should I set PYTHONPATH environment to `%:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\Lib\site-packages`?

I need an exact guide for solving this error

Comment: why don't you use the `mayapy.exe` in `%:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\bin`?

Answer (score 3):

The following code might help you get a standard Python 2.6 as a standalone external interpreter hooked with Maya.

```
################################################################

import os
import sys

#======================================================#
#THESE ARE THE MISSING STUFF WHEN RUNNING pythonw.exe
#======================================================#

os.environ["MAYA_LOCATION"] = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014"
os.environ["PYTHONHOME"]    = "C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python"
os.environ["PATH"] = "C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Maya2014\\bin;" + os.environ["PATH"]

sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib\site-packages\setuptools-0.6c9-py2.6.egg")
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib\site-packages\pymel-1.0.0-py2.6.egg")
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib\site-packages\ipython-0.10.1-py2.6.egg")
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib\site-packages\ply-3.3-py2.6.egg")                         
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\\bin\python26.zip")
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\DLLs")
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib")
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib\plat-win")
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib\lib-tk")
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\\bin")
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python")
sys.path.append("C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Maya2014\Python\lib\site-packages")

import maya.standalone
maya.standalone.initialize(name='python')

################################################################
```

[Source.](http://tech-artists.org/forum/showthread.php?1391-Maya-Python-Can-t-get-Maya-to-initialize-through-external-interpreter-S&p=8883&viewfull=1#post8883)

Comment: Are these the lines we should add to a file or something? Could you please elaborate? Thanks..

Comment: @zingy it doesn't matter whether it's in file or are sequentially typed into the interpretor. What matters is that the above stated code (be careful with the Maya version) should at least once be executed within a Python session and before you import `maya` or `pymel`.

Comment: I'm trying to get my Conda interpreter to work with Maya commands as well as getting auto completion in PyCharm. Whenever I add something like "devkit/path/to/completion/py" to my interpreter's path the auto completion works, but the script doesn't execute. Any ideas?