# "NameError: Can't find file for module maya" while trying to run a Python script in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, maya

I setup Eclipse IDE for editing and debugging Maya scripts. When I try to run the code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
cmds.ls()
```

in Eclipse I get the error:

```
    import maya.cmds as cmds
NameError: Can't find file for module maya
(filename C:\Users\shivani\My Documents\maya)
```

I configured eclipse to use maya and python like the following:

[image]

I don't understand what is the problem or I'm not able to use Eclipse properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Configure](http://pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html) Eclipse to use `mayapy` Python interpreter available in `<Maya_INSTALL_DIR>\bin`.

Or else you will have to initialize the default Python interpreter with Maya as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18566701/1309352).

Comment: I have configured Eclipse to use mayapy.exe already. I followed all the installation process step by step and set the environment variables too. I would re do and see what happens. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running this in Eclipse you'll also have to add

```
import maya.standalone
try:
   maya.standalone.initialize()
except: 
   print "standalone already running"
```

to any code you try to run in the external interpreter.

The maya module is just an empty stub unless running inside a live Maya session or after importing maya.standalone and initializing it as above. The try-catch is good practice because you can only initialize a standalone once.

Comment: OP's error states `NameError: Can't find file for module maya` meaning `maya` is not in the `path` and I think that needs to be taken care of first.

Comment: I tried the with the standalonebut it gives the same error. So I guess I have to re check the installation process again. Thanks.